# How to auto update database mysql using javascript in html

Tags: javascript, mysql, crud, reload

I want to auto update my database when the countdowntimer is == 0 or < 0 without reloading the page. Only a certain block will be reload or reload the script/code. How can i auto update my database in mysql when the distance is < 0? I try the reload(); and .load(location.href("#")); But they reload the page.

I use PHP as my backend

In JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function createCountDown(elementId, date) {

    var countDownDate = new Date(date).getTime();

    var x = setInterval(function() {

      var now = new Date().getTime();

      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = days + 'd ' +
                                                     hours + 'h ' +
                                                     minutes + 'm ' + 
                                                     seconds + 's ';

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Expired";
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: try Ajax for asynchronous Java scripts or put your code in a frame so that it only affects that frame when reloading

Comment: Can you post your PHP?

Comment: what data do you want to update the db with? so we can capture it and send it via ajax to you php to be processed?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use AJAX.

Example:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "path/to/post/handler.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

In your case:

```
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML = "Expired";
    //this is where you update the database:
    xhttp.open("POST", "path/to/post/handler.php", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //use the xhttp object to send(POST) values to the database.
    xhttp.send("message=Expired&id=242");

}
```

[More info Here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

What are you using in the back end?
You will need to handle the JavaScript POST:

Example PHP would be:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";



// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE yourTable SET status=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $_POST['message'], $_POST['id']);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->affected_rows;
$conn->close();
?>
```

Let me know in the comments if it works...

Comment: Your php is invalid. You are mixing two MYSQL API. Mysql_* is also deprecated since php 5 and removed in php 7.

Comment: also, if you use mysqli_* use prepared statements to avoid injections and do not escape strings